# GScript Variable undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I got a problem with my Gscript code my first var is returning as undefined

[image]

[image]

i hope that you can help me resolve my problem

Comment: Add relevant code and error as text and not as image.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because your calling the function without providing a parameter for `info` try providing info a default as follows:

```js
function tst(info) {
  var info=info||['A','B'];
  var a=info[0]!="";
  Logger.log(a);//true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it array that you are passing into sendEmail() function?

If it is array maybe it has only one slot that can be accesed with info[0]?

You can check it easy just add this code at top of your sendEmail function and run it:

```
if(info.constructor === Array && info.length > 1){
  Browser.msgBox("It is array and it is longer than 1");
} else {
  Browser.msgBox("Not array or it is shorter than 1");
}
return;
```

You can modify this code to check separately if it is an array and to check it`s length.